# How to run puppeteer in docker linux container? Getting "Browser process 3261 onExit" in logs?

Tags: docker, puppeteer

I am getting these debug logs when I try and run my puppeteer code within a docker container:

```
puppeteer:browsers:launcher Launching /root/.cache/puppeteer/chrome/linux-121.0.6167.85/chrome-linux64/chrome
  --allow-pre-commit-input
  --disable-background-networking
  --disable-background-timer-throttling
  --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows
  --disable-breakpad
  --disable-client-side-phishing-detection
  --disable-component-update
  --disable-dev-shm-usage
  --disable-field-trial-config
  --disable-hang-monitor
  --disable-infobars
  --disable-ipc-flooding-protection
  --disable-popup-blocking
  --disable-prompt-on-repost
  --disable-renderer-backgrounding
  --disable-search-engine-choice-screen
  --disable-sync
  --enable-automation
  --export-tagged-pdf
  --generate-pdf-document-outline
  --force-color-profile=srgb
  --metrics-recording-only
  --no-first-run
  --password-store=basic
  --use-mock-keychain
  --disable-features=Translate,AcceptCHFrame,MediaRouter,OptimizationHints,ProcessPerSiteUpToMainFrameThreshold
  --enable-features=NetworkServiceInProcess2
  --user-data-dir=/tmp/puppeteer_dev_profile-JLAGWm
  --headless=new
  --hide-scrollbars
  --mute-audio about:blank
  --disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled
  --remote-debugging-port=0
{ detached: true, env: {}, stdio: [ 'pipe', 'ignore', 'pipe' ] }
puppeteer:browsers:launcher Launched 3261
puppeteer:browsers:launcher Browser process 3261 onExit
```

This is after doing:

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer-extra'
import StealthPlugin from 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth'

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin())

puppeteer.launch({ headless: true }).then(browser => {
  // ...
})
```

Any ideas if I need to do anything extra special for docker, or why it is failing to launch?

### Update

I was able to get it working with the `--no-sandbox` argument, so need to figure out a way to have it work without using that.

Comment: Do I need to change my docker file and download chrome manually, like this? https://dev.to/cloudx/how-to-use-puppeteer-inside-a-docker-container-568c